# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SCHEMA'. ERROR With creating it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, database-schema

I am trying to create a view schema, but fell into some problem.

Can you please explain. I#m new to schemas.

```
CREATE VIEW schema.[TEMP1_V](
LOCATION,
OBJECTID,
CTID,
numb,
COUNTALL,
COUNTALL_DEBIT
)
AS SELECT 
LOCATION,
OBJECTID,
CTID,
numb,
COUNTALL,
COUNTALL_DEBIT
COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS COUNTALL,
COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location, IS_DEBIT) AS COUNTALL_DEBIT
FROM ALLOCAMT_V
```

I am getting an error when trying to create it. 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SCHEMA'.'

Comment: is your schema actually called 'schema'? The default value for here is 'dbo'

Comment: Simply remove `schema.`, and the view will be created in the default schema.

Comment: Hi, i tried doing that.. but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean you tried @jarlh suggestion? Why didn't it work? Did you get a (new) error message?

Comment: Also, remove the duplicated columns from the select list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `dbo`.

`dbo` is the Defult schema in SQL Server. If you have your own schema, you can create this view with the `<schema_name>.[TEMP1_v]`

```
    CREATE VIEW dbo.[TEMP1_V]
    AS SELECT 
    LOCATION,
    OBJECTID,
    CTID,
    numb,
    COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS COUNTALL,
    COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location, IS_DEBIT) AS COUNTALL_DEBIT
FROM ALLOCAMT_V
```

Comment: Do we really need the parameters for the VIEW?

Comment: @Arulkumar But can you tell me, is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your schema is actually called `schema`. The default is `dbo` so that's what I've used in the example below. You also don't need to declare your field names as you have. You've also duplicated the `COUNTALL` and `COUNTALL_DEBIT` columns in your select statement.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[TEMP1_V]
AS 
SELECT 
    LOCATION,
    OBJECTID,
    CTID,
    numb,
    COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location) AS COUNTALL,
    COUNT (location) OVER (PARTITION BY location, IS_DEBIT) AS COUNTALL_DEBIT
FROM ALLOCAMT_V
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example is starts off with this:

```
CREATE VIEW
```

So, not knowing how that works, we look up [CREATE VIEW - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956(v=sql.105).aspx) from Microsoft's MSDN page and see the following:

> ```
> CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
> [ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
> AS select_statement 
> [ WITH CHECK OPTION ] [ ; ]
>
> <view_attribute> ::= 
> {
>     [ ENCRYPTION ]
>     [ SCHEMABINDING ]
>     [ VIEW_METADATA ]     }
> ```

We notice that examples of the `VIEW` do not include the columns in the beginning section, so we go back to the definitions on `MSDN` and see the following:

> **schema_name**
>
> Is the name of the `schema` to which the view belongs
>
> *column*
>
> Is the name to be used for a column in a view. A column name is
>   required only when a column is derived from an arithmetic expression,
>   a function, or a constant; when two or more columns may otherwise have
>   the same name, typically because of a join; or when a column in a view
>   is specified a name different from that of the column from which it is
>   derived. **Column names can also be assigned in the SELECT statement**.
>
> **If column is not specified, the view columns acquire the same names as**
>   **the columns in the SELECT statement.**

**UPDATE**: So there is less of a reason to define the columns here since your Query ALREADY DOES THIS.

Which brings us these conclusion:

- Use `MSDN` for syntax issues.
- Only specify the columns in your view if you absolutely have to.
- A view can be created only in the **current** `database`